# How to return results of SQL query to Excel sheet with VBA function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2007

I'm trying to create a VBA function in Excel to affect dynamic value from Access to Excel sheet. This is my code.

```
Public Function SQL(DB As String, Query As String)
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & DB
    SQL = conn.Execute Query
End Function
```

Then I should write on my cell

```
=SQL("file.accdb", "SELECT Count(*) FROM Table")
```

The value returned is `#VALUE!`, but if I change the code to `SQL = 1 + 2`, then the value is `3`.  I believe this means the issue is with `conn.Execute Query.`